# JApplet java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException

Tags: java, json, applet

I have this JApplet jar and tried to open it on the web.
But I keep getting this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException

I've searched the answers here and tried them, but didn't work.
Even if I already added the java-json.jar in my build path of the project.

this is my html code for running my jar file on the web

```
<applet archive="PDDS.jar" code="MainFrame.class" width="960" height="540">
```

I have two classes inside PDDS.jar, the JApplet class is the MainFrame.class, the other one is a class for connecting to the sqlite database.

Answer (score 1):

> Even if I already added the java-json.jar in my build path of the project.

The **build path** of a project has nothing to do with the **runtime** class path, which is set in the `applet` element.

So..

```html
<applet archive="PDDS.jar" code="MainFrame.class" width="960" height="540">
```

Should be more like..

```html
<applet archive="PDDS.jar java-json.jar" code="MainFrame.class" width="960" height="540">
```

Note also that the `code` attribute should best be the fully qualified name of the applet class, **not** the file name, so it would look like:

```html
<applet archive="PDDS.jar java-json.jar" code="MainFrame" width="960" height="540">
```

Comment: Sorry for a very late reply, I was so busy with school. Tried your suggestion, and it resolved my problem above. But now it says that it can't find the MainFrame class